# Why is document.getElementById('foo').value not a reference?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, reference, referenceerror

I'm playing around with the following function and I love it:
`var $ = function( id ) { return document.getElementById( id ); };`

For my current code, I'm **ONLY** ever referring to every element's `value`.
 
So I thought, "why not just update my function to include `.value`?

So this works just fine:

```
var $ = function( id ) { return document.getElementById( id ); };
 $("foo").value = whatever // WORKS JUST FINE :)
```

but this breaks:

```
var $ = function( id ) { return document.getElementById( id ).value; };
$("foo") = whatever // Left side of assignment is not a reference
```

I think I have an idea of what's going on, but since it's hard to put it to words, I'd rather assume I'm wrong.

So what's happening here?

By the way, please feel free to comment:

- IS this a reference error, like I'm assuming?
- Is there a way I can highlight my code to point out the differences between each line better?
- How could I have written my code to show the error all fancy like this picture instead of my comment text (especially how to get it smaller) ?[image: my error image]

Comment: `$("foo").value = whatever` assigns `whatever` to the `value` property of the node object that was returned. `$("foo") = whatever` attempts to assign a value to a value (similar with assigning a string to another string) and you're right that that is a ReferenceError.

Comment: `document.getElementById('foo').value` actually **is** (an expression that evaluates to) a reference. Your problem is that the function call `$("foo")` is not, because functions can't return references.

Answer (score 2):

An element's `.value` is *actually* a setter/getter. When the following

```
document.getElementById( id ).value
```

is evaluated as an *expression* (like in `$`, where you're trying to return it), rather than being assigned to, the getter is invoked, and it evaluates to a primitive. So, to the interpreter:

```
return document.getElementById( id ).value;
```

turns into something like

```
return 'someValue';
```

So, when `$` is called, some string is returned, but just like

```
'someValue' = 'newValue'
```

doesn't work, neither does

```
$("foo") = 'newValue';
```

For what you're trying to do to work, you would have to *invoke* the setter, by assigning to the `.value` *property*. Once the `.value` has been evaluated as an expression (such as on the right hand side of a `return`), you've already invoked the getter.

One possible method to invoke the setter would be:

```
const set$ = (id, newVal) => {
  document.getElementById(id).value = newVal;
};
set$('foo', 'myNewVal');
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So essentially, while we can't reference `.value` we COULD lookup `getElementByID()`'s respective `.setValue()` and use that just fine?

Comment: You'd either have to assign to `.value`, with `.value` on the left hand side, or call / do something that does.

Answer (score 1):

In the second function the return value of `$("foo")` is a string. You can't assign to a string:

```js
var $ = function( id ) { return document.getElementById( id ).value; };
console.log(typeof $("foo"), $("foo"))
```

```html
<input id="foo" value = "Bar"/>
```

There are a lot of option. You could let your function take a second parameter that is used to set the value:

```js
var $ = function(id, val) {
  let el = document.getElementById(id)
  if (val !== undefined) {
    el.value = val
  }
  return el
}

console.log($("foo", "test"))
```

```html
<input id="foo" value="Bar" />
```

But it might be clearer just to return the element, and assign the value or make a new set value function.